# Strong convergence and convergence of integral

Tags: measure-theory

A sequence of probability measures $\{\mu_n\}$ converges strongly if for each measurable set $A$

$$\mu_{n}(A) \rightarrow \mu(A)$$

(notice that this convergence is different than the total variation)

when does this convergence imply

$$\int f \,d\mu_n\to \int f \,d\mu $$

for every bounded measurable function? I'm interested in the case in which the space is not Polish.

Comment: Are all the $\mu_n$-s probabilities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{nrm}[1]{\left\lVert{#1}\right\rVert}\newcommand{abs}[1]{\left\lvert{#1}\right\rvert}$It always does. I'll use the notation $\mu(f):=\int f\,d\mu$ throughout. Essentially, you can use the fact that all the $\mu$-s are probabilities on $X$ (or the slightly weaker fact that $M=\sup_{n\in\Bbb N}\mu_n(X)$ and $\mu(X)$ are finite).

The result is obvious for simple functions. Now, recall that every bounded measurable function is uniform limit of simple functions. Namely, $$f_n:=\sum_{k=-2n}^{2n-1} \frac kn\cdot 1_{f^{-1}\left[\frac kn,\frac{k+1}n\right)}$$ satisfies $\nrm{f-f_n}_\infty\le\frac1n$ for all $n>\sup_{x\in X}\abs{f(x)}$.

Finally, for any fixed $\delta>0$ consider some simple function $g$ such that $\nrm{f-g}_\infty<\delta$ and observe that, for all $n$, $$\abs{\mu(f)-\mu_n(f)}\le\abs{\mu(f-g)}+\abs{\mu(g)-\mu_n(g)}+\abs{\mu_n(g-f)}\le\\\le (\mu(X)+\mu_n(X))\nrm{f-g}_\infty+\mu_n(g-f)\le (1+M)\delta+\abs{\mu(g)-\mu_n(g)}$$

The last quantity is a sequence converging to $(1+M)\delta$. Therefore, for all $\delta>0$ $$\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}\abs{\mu(f)-\mu_n(f)}\le (1+M)\delta$$

Therefore $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}\abs{\mu(f)-\mu_n(f)}=0$.

Comment: This seems good. Some clarifications. What is $M$ in the second to last displayed equation? Also the last two equations should probably have $f$’s instead of $X$’s.

Comment: @Condor5 $M$ is $\sup_n\mu_n(X)$.

Comment: Thanks, then the term that is left after the second inequality should be $\mu(g)-\mu_n(g)$ (and the last equation, after therefore should also have an $f$)

Comment: @Condor5 true, thanks.